# Treating a model as an instance of imported class in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a class for manipulating certain data.
In that class I calculate and validate the data.
Then, is there a way to apply this calculation and validation to  an instance of Django model?
Ideally, I would like to store an instance of the imported class in the database. 
I came up with two methods.

- 1.Make another class to connect model and imported class.
- 2.Write validation and calculations directly in models.py.

Which is better?
Is there another good way?
If 2 is good, how to do that?
Here is a very simple example.

```
# in models.py
class Person(models.Modes):
    name = models.CharField()
    gender = models.CharField()
    age = models.IntegerField()
    valid   = models.NullBooleanField(blank=True)

# in other files
class AboutPerson:# I want to apply this class to above model instance.
    def __init__(self, name, gender, age):
        self.name =name
        self.gender = gender
        self.age = age
        self.valed = None

    def validate_age(self):
        self.valid =  self.age >= 20

    def other_validate(self, age):
        self.valid = self.age >= age
```

In this example, I want to apply change of self.valid to model automatically.
Now, I adopt 2. This is also a simple example.

```
class FromModel:
    '''
        obj:object obtained from database
        This class passes the value received from the database to the class imported from the module.
        Attribute:
    '''

    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj        = obj
        self.instance   = AboutPerson(name=obj.name, gender=obj.gender, age=obj.age)

    def update(self):#use this method after some validation has done.
        self.obj.valid = self.instance.valid
        self.obj.save()
```

I wish you could understand my poor explanation...
Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Is this `model` for on screen use?  I ask to verify because it looks like you are wanting a `modelform` that uses that model and also subclasses your already written class for validation/verification.  That validation can also be put into an oveerridden `clean` method of a `modelform`

Comment: Sorry, I do not know what "on screen" is pointing to.
But I know modelform. I believe that modelform is a class to store the input data as an instance of the model in the database. Perhaps my example cited a misunderstanding. I don't only want to validate when I input, but also I want to extract and operate a model instance that already exists in the database.

Comment: Ideally, I would like to store an instance of the imported class in the database.

Comment: are you trying to use just the django ORM/ database abstraction layer for storing instances of your existing class?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to do so.

Comment: If you are not going to be using the html aspect then a `modelform` does not really make sense for you. I can't really answer what I now understand to be your question.  I would think that either approach would work. If this is an existing code base that you are modifying to use the django DB interface, what has the code been using for data storage? and why change it now?

Comment: I modified the code slightly to the actual one. I want you to check it!  I'm planning to add multiple models that are similar but slightly different. I think that the code is too redundant in my method.

Answer (score 1):

As Alan Hoover said, if you aren't planning on needing to validate the form data from user input then I don't think you should use a form.

My suggestion is to keep the validation of the model in the model. There is a built in method for validation: [Model.clean()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean). So using your example:

models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def clean(self):
        if self.age < 21:
            raise ValidationError('No beer for you!')
        if self.name == 'Charles':
            self.name = 'Charley'
```

views.py

```
def my_function():
    # ...
    my_person_obj.clean()
    my_person_obj.save()
```

Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: You really understand me:) Models.clean() seems to be a good idea for me. I will give it a try!